# How to display current langage on top of the langage list in a content type

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I am using **drupal 7.54** and I am a bit in trouble.

I have made a multilingual website based on **entity translation**.

I created a **custom content type** that users can create or edit nodes with. And that content type has a **language field**.

But in that dropdown field, **English shows first in both languages**. It confuses french users. 
So I need to **make the current language the first on the list of languages**. 
As an example I want the list to display like this

- Français
- Anglais

when viewing the site in **French** version. And :

- English
- French

when viewing the site in **English**.

Hopefully I explained the problem properly, I'll be very happy to know what to do.

I need help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit your content type, you should have a `Language settings` tab, I guess you have on Default Language "Site's default" and not the current interface language.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did work. I went to "multilingual setting" -> Set custom language as default for new content and let "Custom default language" at "current language". It work!!!!!!

Comment: Np, don't hesitate to accept the answer if it solves your problem and can help future viewers.

Comment: @mosgeorges Please have a look at [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) ... it explains what "you" are expected to do if you get an answer to a question that did help you (and/or actually solved your issue). for short, as per your prior comments, it appears to me that at least you should mark this answer as ***accepted***, similar to hat is also suggested in the prior comment (if you do, you'll receive another small surprise yourself also ... aka +2 rep points). And BTW, do not hesitate to also ***upvote*** it if you want to do so ... like I just did also ..